# Swiper plugin align last slide to the right

Tags: jquery, css, slider, touch, swiper.js

I am using awesome mobile touch swiper slider. It works fine.

But I have an issue I couldn't find any answer for that on the net.

http://starteacher.co.kr/main/main

I put multiple slides on swiper container area and move them one by one. It works fine with multiple slides. But the last slide has a blank space.

How can I align last slide to the right of the swiper container? So it doesn't have any blank space. I want the container fully covered  with slides without any blank space.

See the link for your understanding.

Comment: When your question will be answered, the link you provided will no longer be helpful for others in order to understand the question and learn from solution. Please create a [mcve] of your problem here, in the question, using the `<>` button.

Answer (score 0):

this might be an answer that will be frowned upon, but I thought I should give my input to you never the less. I followed your link and I messed around with the styling using the developer tools, and what I noticed work to my understanding of your issue is the following:

```
@media (min-width: 1024px)
navbar-top-fixed.css:435
.swiper-slide{
 width: 27%;
}
```

I just added an extra 1% to it and the card filled the view, perhaps you can find a way to add this styling in your site? Hope this helps.